# What does steam condensation for reuse mean in a steam turbine?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, energy, condensed-matter, experimental-physics

So I'm always confused how this LOOKS like when done. I imagine two ways:

1. Sending the high-pressure hot steam in pipes that coil into and go out of the water tank. Here the steam loses its internal energy to the water in the tank making the water hotter. Then this cooled steam is collected as condensate.
2. releasing the high-pressure hot steam directly back into the water tank, (bubbling it in the liquid or releasing it in the "headspace" above the liquid water)

Which one is it and why is it more efficient/suitable/safer than the other?

Comment: Real thermal power plants use a separate _condenser_ that rejects heat to the environment. Typically, either to a nearby body of water (a river or a so-called, "cooling pond") or to the air via. cooling towers. Remember, a heat engine extracts power from the _flow_ of heat from a heat source to a heat sink. The greater the temperature difference between the source and the sink, the more power can be extracted from the flow.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Is a steam turbine classified as a heat engine? Sorry if this sounds dumb. I'm a learner.

Comment: @SolomonSlow What difference does it make whether we reject heat to the environment, or to the source of steam (a water tank for instance)? The latter will result in a higher energy supply as the coal AND the exhaust steam will provide energy now?

Comment: A [turbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbine) is a kind of machine that extracts mechanical energy from a fluid flow. The whole system, of which the turbines are a part in a power plant, is a kind of [heat engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine).

Comment: @SolomonSlow What about my second comment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about when you say, "the water tank." There's probably several water tanks that serve different purposes in a big power plant, but it sounds like maybe you are talking about the _boiler._ If that's the case, then you _can't_ reject heat to the boiler because the temperature of the boiler is the same as the temperature of the steam at the turbine's inlet. Heat can only flow (and the engine can only produce power) if there is a temperature _difference_. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnbiVw_1FNs (skip ahead to 1:30 for the good part or, to 2:05 for the song.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensing_steam_locomotive will help for steam locomotive uses